# Java- Streams with buffered

Tags: java

So recently i have learned to work with streams, both with input and output to learn so i can read from a file and write to one. But my teacher sometimes decides to use buffered and sometimes he does not. Like in this case ill post the code. Do you guys understand why he has not put an bufferedoutputstream in this case?

```
  public void writePrimes2(String filename) throws IOException {
        try(ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename))){
            os.writeObject(primes);
            os.flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Buffered is faster than Non-buffered. Maybe he didn't want to write some extra code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BufferedOutputStream and FileOutputStream both work similarly.  Internally BufferedOutputStream  writes to a internal buffer and not directly to the Operating System IO device and when the buffer is full or closed, it flushes the contents of the buffer to the OS IO device.  This can be more efficient/faster on some OS.  But the result is that the output can appear slightly delayed because of buffering.

Comment: Thank you very much! But what i dont understand is, in which instances do you choose to use buffered or fileoutput.

Comment: [The Java Tutorials/IO ]https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html  has some good explanations.  FileOutputStream  is considered primitive/low level compared to BufferedOutputStream  and supposed to be used with binary/raw data such as an image file.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectOutputStream` is used serialize the state of an object (instance variables' values). if the object is small enough, then the whole operation will likely be sufficiently fast.